# Spring RestTemplate Response values all null

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Ok, the issue I am having is that I can succesfully make a post call using RestTemplate. The request completes successfully on the server side.

However, when it goes to get set on client side the values do not get assigned properly. The first class below is the client side that should be populated by the Post call. The second class is the one that is being used by the server to send it.

I believe my issue arises because of the JSON format that the server sends over. It looks something like the below.

```
{ "record":{"firstName":"Bill", "lastName":"Johnson", "role":6}}
```

Spring can not automatically map this into the Client side POJO. is there a way around this without having to change the server side code?

Thank you.

```
EmployeeResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, EmployeeResponse.class );

//(Client Side)
public class EmployeeResponse {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int role;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName= firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return longKey;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName= lastName;
    }
    public int getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(int role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}

//(Server-Side)
public class EmployeeResponse {

    private EmployeeRecord record;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return record.getFirstName();
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return record.getLastName();
    }

    public int getRole() {
        return record.getRole();
    }

    public ELAActivationResponse(EmployeeRecord record) {
        this.record = record;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because because the server response is wrapped with root element `record` and your client object doesn't, so its unable to marshal the response.

You need to annotate your response object class(`EmployeeResponse`) with `@JsonRootName(value = "record")`